# Keyboard Shortcuts For Navigating Spotlight?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

I find keyboard shortcuts very useful, and whilst I know quite a few of the "general ones", I don't know any concerning using **Spotlight** with the exception of

**Command-SpaceBar** to launch it.

What other keyboard shortcuts exist (if any) with regards to using **Spotlight** (that may make things "lightening fast" when using it) ?

(I'm sure the number of shortcuts available cannot be that extensive - if they exist that is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ⌘R or ⌘↩ reveals an item in Finder
- ⌘I shows an information window
- ⌘Y shows a Quick Look window
- ⌘D selects a dictionary result
- ⌘B selects a web search result
- ⌘K selects a Wikipedia result
- ⌘T selects the top result
- ⌘, opens Spotlight preferences
- Holding command shows a preview popover
- Holding option and command shows the full path of a file in a preview popover
- ⌘↓ moves to the next section and ⌘↑ moves to the previous section
- ⌃↓, end, or page down selects the last item

Comment: This is life-changing!

Comment: "Holding command shows a preview popover" Thank you! I always wanted a keyboard shortcut for this and didn't realize there was one.

Answer (score 3):

### 4 Basic Spotlight Shortcuts

These are the most basic shortcuts to use Spotlight:

Open Spotlight menu – Command+Space

Open Spotlight in the Finder – Command+Option+Space

Clear Spotlight search box – Escape

Close Spotlight menu – Escape twice

### 7 Spotlight Usage & Navigation Keyboard Shortcuts

These shortcuts are for interacting and navigating within Spotlight search results:

Open first search item – Return

Navigate search results – Arrow Up and Arrow Down

Open to location of first search item in Finder – Command+Return

Get Info on search item – Command+I

Show Quick Look Preview of Spotlight results – Command key or hover with the Mouse cursor (OS X 10.7 and later only)

Show path/location of search result – Command+Option while hovering over search result

Jump categories in search results – Command+Arrow Up or Command+Arrow Down

Take a look at [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/09/spotlight-keyboard-shortcuts/) for more details.